# Right way to use celery.app.control in celery

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery latest stable version 4.4.7. And recently want to use `celery.app.control` package (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.control.html).

According to the API, I tried following code but this did not work. And I found another package `celery.task.control` does work but seems it will be removed in 5.0. So I'd like to use `celery.app.control`. Anyone knows the difference between them and how to use `celery.app.control` in the right way? Thanks.

I already went through the celery document guide and also search in google but did not find the answer. BTW, I would complain celery documentation is bad, it contains lots of inconsistence and errors. :)

**Does work**

```py
>>> from celery.task.control import inspect
>>> i = inspect()
>>> i.registered()
{'celery@centos72_base': ['core.tasks.task1', 'core.tasks.task2']}

>>> i.active()
{'celery@centos72_base': []}
```

**Not work**

```py
>>> from celery.app.control import Inspect 
>>> i = Inspect(app='test')
>>> i.active()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 119, in active
    return self._request('active')
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 98, in _request
    return self._prepare(self.app.control.broadcast(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'control'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of what I do in various monitoring scripts:

```
app = Celery("myapp", include=["myproject.tasks", "myproject.other.tasks"])
app.config_from_object(myproject.celeryconfig)

insp = app.control.inspect()
active_lst = insp.active()
for key in active_lst.keys():
    print(key)
```

I never even tried inspect/monitoring API without using a Celery instance...

Comment: Thanks @DejanLekic, yes, this works. Still don't know how to use celery.app.control. I will try to find out.